# Laravel 8: ReflectionException Function () does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, web, routes, laravel-8

I'm a beginner learning how to use Laravel 8.
When I tried to execute my code, I got the error:ReflectionException Function () does not exist.

I've referred the syntax in the Laravel document #Writing Controllers, #Basic Controllers part, but the problem can't be solved.

What is the reason causing this problem and how to solve it?

The following code is my controller part in PurchaseController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;


class PurchasesController extends Controller
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('purchases.index');
    }

    public function purchase()
    {
        //
    }
```

The following part is my routing in web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PurchaseController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/purchases', [PurchaseController::class], 'index');
Route::post('/purchases', [PurchaseController::class], 'purchase');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Updating:
I've changed my code web.app code into following, according to the answers provided below. However, I got another error message: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController] does not exist.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/purchases', [PurchasesController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/purchases', [PurchasesController::class , 'purchase']);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

My updating PurchaseController.php code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;


class PurchasesController extends Controller   //Change the naming as suggestion below
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function index()
    {
        return view('purchases.index');
    }

    public function purchase()
    {
        //
    }
```

Comment: Routes is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your routes like this:

and change PurchaseController to PurchasesController

```
Route::get('/purchases', [PurchasesController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/purchases', [PurchasesController::class, 'purchase']);
```

and

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController;
```

Comment: I tried this, and get the error: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [PurchaseController] does not exist. 

I think "use App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController;" this not gonna work, because my file name is PurchaseController.php

Comment: you have a naming problem, if your class name is PurchaseController then go and fix class itselfs: class PurchasesController extends Controller

Comment: I changed the class name into PurchasesController exteneds Controller as your suggestion, but I still got the error.
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController] does not exist.

I've ensured that I save the changes, and rerun the "php artisan serve".

Comment: thats weird try this one:

Route::get('/purchases', [App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController::class, 'index']);

Route::post('/purchases', [App\Http\Controllers\PurchasesController::class, 'purchase']);

Comment: did you made any changes to your App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php ?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything.
I've only edited this two files only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236290/discussion-between-behzad-and-goro).

Answer (score 0):

=> Open App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php and uncomment this line try this in laravel 8

protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';